# Replace multiple whitespaces inside HTML elements with &nbsp;

Tags: html, css, regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

I have large amounts of html similar to

```
<div>some text</div>
```

**with multiple whitespaces**, which I would like to replace with

```
<div>some&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text</div>
```

Is there a way to do this an HTML editor like notepad++/dreamweaver? My problem is isolating only the whitespaces trailing/following text.

Comment: you're missing the semi-colon on the end of `&nbsp;`

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple spaces in a row?

Comment: for what purposes do you need it? There are CSS-ways to control the behaviour of whitespaces.

Comment: Just need to preserve white space. My question wasn't actually clear. Say i have two white spaces between characters, and when the browser renders it, all of them collapse to a single one. white-space:pre-wrap seems ideal, but doesnt seem to work in IE7

Comment: @Michael - exactly. I wrote the question wrong; apologies.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter mentioned, it should be `&nbsp;` .

You should be able to do a simple find and replace, replacing space with `&nbsp;`.  Notepad++ definitely has this feature.

One thing to realize is that nbsp stands for non-breaking space, or put another way, a space that will never allow a line break.  If you have a large block of text with all nbsp's, it will all appear on one line and may require horizontal scrolling to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for using any editor and modify your HTML then you can use replace all feature of notepad++.

The short cut to open replace all dialog box is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>H</kbd>. In this dialog box you should enter the string to find and string to replace with  and then click on replace.

I hope this makes sense to you. You don't need javascript to do this.

Comment: In that case how can i isolate only the white spaces inside elements, and not between tags? Some help finding a regex that does this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#theDiv").text( $("#theDiv").html().replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;") );
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="theDiv">something in here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if a Javascript solution would work here. When i inspect the code in the browser(IE7), all i see is a single whites pace where there were multiple ones in source. Am i missing something here? My objective is to convert every single white space in to an &nbsp tag, or achieve a similar effect to a <pre> tag without using it.